# Como acessar uma Activity clicando na notificação sem perder os dados

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-notification

Olá, eu gostaria de pedir ajuda pois eu montei um app com um cronômetro e depois de muito tempo consegui habilitar notificações para o Android Oreo+, porém eu não consigo acessar a activity do cronômetro através dessa notificação
e gostaria também se puder, me ajudar a abrir a activity do cronômetro via notificação sem que o mesmo reinicie

segue abaixo o código

NotificationHelper.java

```
public NotificationHelper(Context base) {
    super(base);
    createChannels();

}

private void createChannels() {
    NotificationChannel myChannel = new NotificationChannel(MY_CHANNEL_ID, MY_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    myChannel.enableLights(true);


    getManager().createNotificationChannel(myChannel);
}

public NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (manager == null)
        manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    return manager;

}


public Notification.Builder getmyChannelNotification(String title, String body) {

    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), MY_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setContentText("Acesso rápido ao app")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.timer_notification);
}
```

}

chronometer.java

```
  private NotificationChannel NotificationChannel;
private TextView Title;
private TextView Content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chronometer);

    helper = new NotificationHelper(this);
    Title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Title);
    Content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Content);
    notificationbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.notificationbtn);
    notificationbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String title = Title.getText().toString();
            String content = Content.getText().toString();
            Notification.Builder builder = helper.getmyChannelNotification(title, content );
            helper.getManager().notify(new Random().nextInt(),builder.build());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá!

Para abrir a activity a partir da notificação é necessário informar isso no Notification.Builder.

Isso pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
 // Cria um Intent da Activity que você deseja abrir
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityQueVoceQuerAbrir.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
// Cria um PendingIntent a partir da intent criada acima
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Agora com a pending intent em mão, você precisa informar ela no Notification.Builder. Veja:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
```

No método setContentIntent é onde passamos a PendingIntent criada, informando assim que desejamos que essa Intent seja acionada quando o usuário clicar na notificação!

Agora quanto ao problema de perder a contagem do cronômetro ao fechar o app, você terá de persistir esse dado de forma que ele fique salvo mesmo se o usuário fechar o app.

O que você pode fazer é olhar [esse tópico aqui que ensina como salvar dados no SQLite localmente no Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite). Assim que você souber como salvar os dados localmente, basta você salvar a hora que o cronômetro começou, e sempre que abrir a activity, ler essa hora e calcular quanto tempo passou, e dai começar o cronômetro a partir dai!